# Plotting colored lines connecting individual data points of two swarmplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data
set1 = np.random.randint(0, 40, 24)
set2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 24)

# Put into dataframe and plot
df = pd.DataFrame({'set1': set1, 'set2': set2})
data = pd.melt(df)
sb.swarmplot(data=data, x='variable', y='value')
```

The two random distributions plotted with seaborn's swarmplot function:
[image: The two random distributions plotted with seaborns swarmplot function]

I want the individual plots of both distributions to be connected with a colored line such that the first data point of set 1 in the dataframe is connected with the first data point of set 2.
I realize that this would probably be relatively simple without seaborn but I want to keep the feature that the individual data points do not overlap.
Is there any way to access the individual plot coordinates in the seaborn swarmfunction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: Thanks to @Mead, who pointed out a bug in my post prior to 2021-08-23 (I forgot to sort the locations in the prior version).**

I gave the nice answer by [Paul Brodersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51157346/5201771) a try, and despite him saying that

> Madness lies this way

... I actually think it's pretty straight forward and yields nice results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Generate random data
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
set1 = rng.integers(0, 40, 5)
set2 = rng.integers(0, 100, 5)

# Put into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"set1": set1, "set2": set2})
print(df)
data = pd.melt(df)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.swarmplot(data=data, x="variable", y="value", ax=ax)

# Now connect the dots
# Find idx0 and idx1 by inspecting the elements return from ax.get_children()
# ... or find a way to automate it
idx0 = 0
idx1 = 1
locs1 = ax.get_children()[idx0].get_offsets()
locs2 = ax.get_children()[idx1].get_offsets()

# before plotting, we need to sort so that the data points
# correspond to each other as they did in "set1" and "set2"
sort_idxs1 = np.argsort(set1)
sort_idxs2 = np.argsort(set2)

# revert "ascending sort" through sort_idxs2.argsort(),
# and then sort into order corresponding with set1
locs2_sorted = locs2[sort_idxs2.argsort()][sort_idxs1]

for i in range(locs1.shape[0]):
    x = [locs1[i, 0], locs2_sorted[i, 0]]
    y = [locs1[i, 1], locs2_sorted[i, 1]]
    ax.plot(x, y, color="black", alpha=0.1)
```

It prints:

```
   set1  set2
0     3    85
1    30     8
2    26    69
3    17    20
4    17     9
```

And you can see that the data is linked correspondingly in the plot.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I didnt really test that but it seems very straightforward. Thanks for this. You're only missing `import seaborn as sns` and can delete one of the `import numpy as np`.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it! --> yes, I now also used this method for a 2x2 plot (so lots of more dots) and it worked equally straight forward. The only "difficult" part is finding which of the ax's "children" are the objects to use.

Comment: Isn't this solution just joining the top-most point of `set1` with the top-most point of `set2`? I don't think it's successfully joining points that occupy the same row in the original data frame (which are random, and therefore I'd expect the lines to be jumbled).

Comment: I think you are right @Mead ... I'll look into this and see if it can be easily solved with a sorting before plotting.

Comment: It's fixed now. Thanks a ton for checking it and making me/us aware via a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible (but you really don't want to).

`seaborn.swarmplot` returns the axis instance (here: `ax`). You can grab the children `ax.get_children` to get all plot elements. You will see that for each set of points there is an element of type `PathCollection`. You can determine the x, y coordinates by using the `PathCollection.get_offsets()` method.

**I do not suggest you do this! Madness lies this way.**

I suggest you have a look at the source code ([found here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/ce90b66646f1c71a4caec8a0590e10dfec5d6480/seaborn/categorical.py)), and derive your own `_PairedSwarmPlotter` from `_SwarmPlotter` and change the `draw_swarmplot` method to your needs.